# Quotes when using grep?

Tags: regex, grep, quotes

Grep acts differently depending on what kind of quotes I surround the regex with. I can't seem to get a clear understanding of why this is. Here is an example of the problem:

```
hamiltont$ grep -e show\(  test.txt 
  variable.show();
  variable.show(a);
  variable.show(abc, 132);
  variableshow();
hamiltont$ grep -e "show\("  test.txt 
grep: Unmatched ( or \(
hamiltont$ grep -e 'show\('  test.txt 
grep: Unmatched ( or \(
```

I am just assuming there is some proper way to enclose the regex with single/double quotes. Any help?

FWIW, `grep --version` returns `grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The command line including the arguments is processed by the shell before it is executed. You can use *echo* to see what the shell does:

```
$ echo grep -e show\(  test.txt 
grep -e show( test.txt

$ echo grep -e "show\("  test.txt 
grep -e show\( test.txt

$ echo grep -e 'show\('  test.txt 
grep -e show\( test.txt
```

So without quotes the backslash gets removed making the "(" a normal character for grep (grep uses *basic* regex by default, use -E to make grep use *extended* regex).

Comment: I still don't get what is the difference between single and double quotes. In the example you posted, they seem to do the same thing.

Comment: What if I have a grep regex that should match a single quote or a double quote, how can I write it with grep? `grep '["]\'"` doesn't seem work...

Comment: single and double quotes do the same thing for our purposes. To match a quote just use " or '. If surrounding the pattern in quotes, use the different quote to the one you want to match, e.g. matching " within a pattern would be 'foo"bar'

Comment: For both types of quotes inside pattern, use single quotes around outer command and escape with \' see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23347/wrapping-a-command-that-includes-single-and-double-quotes-for-another-command

Comment: In this specific case `echo` is sufficient to show what the shell is doing, but _very, very often_ it is not (and for someone to know a priori if `echo` would be sufficient, they would need to understand shell parsing enough to not need to ask the question at all). For example, one can't use `echo` to tell the difference between `echo "hello world"` and `echo "hello" "world"`. It's a better habit to teach people to use `set -x`, or even `printcmd() { printf '%q ' "$@"; echo; }` and then `printcmd grep -e show\( test.txt`. (In bash 5, `printcmd() { echo "${@@Q}"; }` is a shorter alternative).

Answer (score 5):

In order:

```
grep -e show( test.txt
```

does not work, because the shell interprets the `(` as special, a parenthesis, not just a character, and can't find the closing `)`.

These both work:

```
grep -e 'show(' test.txt
grep -e "show(" test.txt
```

because the shell treats the quoted text as just text, and passes it to grep.

These do not work:

```
grep -e 'show\(' test.txt
grep -e "show\(" test.txt
```

because the shell passes `show\(` to grep, grep sees `\(` as special, a parenthesis, not just a character, and can't find the closing `\)`.

Answer (score 3):

The quotes change what grep sees.  The backslash (\) in the un-quoted form is processed by the shell, which treats characters after the backslash as special.  This happens before grep gets the parameter.  grep sees **show(**.  When the quotes (single or double) are used, the shell interprets them as "leave the contents alone", thus grep sees **show\(** and the **\(** characters have meaning in grep and it is looking for the closing parenthesis - \).

BTW: Single and double quote handling is different in how the shell handles shell variables, but there are no shell variables in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe it is grep that is behaving differently, it is the shell.  I'm assuming you are using bash

http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_8.html

Basically the quoted versions are behaving differently on the slash, depending on the quoting mechanism.

Both of the quoted examples would have worked without the slash.  For the first one, the shell would escape the ( and pass in just show( to the grep for the pattern.