# Grep : find patterns in text file

Tags: linux, grep

I have to find the following patterns in  a text file

```
\xc2d 
d\xa0 
\xe7 
\xc3\ufffdd 
\xc3\ufffdd 
\xc2\xa0 
\xc3\xa7 
\xa0\xa0
```

I start with finding `\x` occurrences and do this

```
 grep "\\x" *.log | more
```

and nothing returns, is this query correct?

Comment: Either the contents of your file is not the same as the one you showed us or the file does not end in .log. I ran the same query on a file with those exact lines in it and I got all the lines back (as I should have).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll want to use single quotes instead of double quotes.

`grep '\\x' *.log | more`

Your shell is likely [stripping that first backslash as part of the processing it does for strings in double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008423/quotes-when-using-grep), which grep needs.